# How do I subtract 2 values that need to be concatenated in sql?

Tags: sql

I am using a sql query that spools into a csv file, separated by single quotes. I need to subtract 2 columns but not able to use the minus operator. * and / works but not + and -.

How can I use the minus operator?

eg :

- `select ''''||10-2||'''' from dual` ---> Does not work
- `select ''''||10*2||'''' from dual` ---> works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
select ''''||(10 - 2)||'''' from dual;
```

output -

```
'8'
```